# Neos 2.1: Unable to add new page/interact with backend

Tags: neoscms

I got another problem with Neos. Whenever I try to add a new Page/Shortcut/... the Backend, the top left area becomes mostly unuseable. [Top left area after I tried to add new elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDcDj.png)

I cannot switch pages, but can edit the current page.
When I push things to live, or refresh the site, the added 'null'-pages disapeer.
Copy/Paste works without problems.
As long as I not try to move things in top left area no error appears.
And no javascript request or network traffic is visible when creating new page elements.

But I don't know how to get rid of this and even don't know where to start search.

Hope you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice, with a shot in the dark(hope that I used that right) I,ve figured it out. Somwhere in my CSS was something that was in conflict with Neos, so that the inputfield disapeared.

So the solution for that problem was to disable all my css.